# Create in a html

Tags: html, razor

I'm trying to create a create page for register product ,but i'm having multiple errors in a block of code and can't find the solution.

```
{
                                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Produto.ListProdutoEmpresaImagem.Count; i++)
                                    {
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Produto.ListProdutoEmpresaImagem[i].ProdutoEmpresaImagemId)
                                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Produto.ListProdutoEmpresaImagem[i].Url)
                                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Produto.ListProdutoEmpresaImagem[i].DataCadastro)
                                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Produto.ListProdutoEmpresaImagem[i].Home)
                                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Produto.ListProdutoEmpresaImagem[i].Details)

                                    if (this.Model.Produto.ListProdutoEmpresaImagem[i].excluir == false)
                                                {
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><span class="spanImagemPrincipal" ref="@i">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Produto.ListProdutoEmpresaImagem[i].Destaque, new { @Class = "ckbImagemPrincipal" }) Sim</span></td>
                                            <td><img src='@WebCommons.Helper.AppSettingsHelper.GetStringSettings("PATH_VIRTUAL_UPLOAD")@WebCommons.Helper.AppSettingsHelper.GetStringSettings("PATH_VIRTUAL_UPLOAD_ST_IMAGEM_PEQUENA")@Model.Produto.ListProdutoEmpresaImagem alt="Imagem do Produto"  /></td>
                                            <td><a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remover" onclick="ExcluirImagem('@(i)');"><i class="icon-trash bigger-120" , id="hiddenexcluiridimagem" ></i></a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                                }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Produto.ListProdutoEmpresaImagem[i].excluir)
                                        }
                                       }
                                  }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="3">Nenhum resultado encontrado</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        }
```

I'm getting 3 erros,in the first for i'm getting "The block is missing the character "}" ".But i checked and for me its right.
The second one is in "onclick="ExcluirImagem('@(i)');" ",i'm getting unexpected token
And last one in the "" saying unmatched closing tag.

Someone know what is causing this erros,the close tagas look like its right to me.

[image: This is the errors]
EDIT 1:

I comment the following block

```
 @*<tr>


<td><span class="spanArquivoTipo" ref="@i">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Produto.ListProdutoArquivoProduto[i].ProdutoArquivo.ProdutoArquivoTipo.Descricao)</span></td>
                                            <td><span class="spanArquivo" ref="@i"><a ref="@i" href='@WebCommons.Helper.AppSettingsHelper.GetStringSettings("PATH_VIRTUAL_UPLOAD")@WebCommons.Helper.AppSettingsHelper.GetStringSettings("PATH_VIRTUAL_UPLOAD_ST_ARQUIVO")@Model.Produto.ListProdutoArquivoProduto[i].ProdutoArquivo. target="_blank">@Model.Produto.ListProdutoArquivoProduto[i].ProdutoArquivo.Capa</a></span></td>
                                            <td><a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remover" onclick="ExcluirArquivo('@(i)');"><i class="icon-trash bigger-120"  id="hiddenexcluiridarquivo"></i></a></td>
                                        </tr>*@
```

With this block commented i dont get the error "The if block is missing the "}""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether you have all this code wrapped in a form or not, so I'm going to point out the obvious; You need `@` before your `for and if`. In the `onclick="ExcluirImagem('@(i)')"` try removing the parentheses `onclick="ExcluirImagem('@i')"`

Is `ExcluirImagem` expecting a character or an integer? If it's expecting an integer, no need to wrap `@i` in single-quotes. `onclick="ExcluirImagem(@i)"`

Comment: Its not a form,didn't work,i use resharper and it says to remove the @ before the for and if.And in the @(i) the error continues even with the changes.

Comment: Is the code provided the entire View, or was this just a snippet?

Comment: Just a snippet,i got the same error in other 2 places in the code,but the blocks is praticly the same.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. One thing to try, is to count your curly braces and make sure they balance out. For example `open brace - add 1...close brace - subtract 1` and when you're finished, you should end right back at the number you started from. I start from 0.

Comment: The brackets are matching alright,i add a picture of the error.The three errors i said above.

Comment: The braces are not matching. The braces result in a -1 count from the image above from the `first if` to the `first else`. Also, it looks like your `img` tag is having some difficulties in resolving, this may also lead to some errors you're experiencing. Try removing the `;` in the call to `ExcluirImagem` in the `onclick` event handler. Quick note, to format your file quickly to the built-in standard, do the following: `1. ctrl+a   2. ctrl+k,f` Save you a lot of time properly formatting your code.

Comment: I cant find the missing bracket,i counted 5 open brackets and 5 closing.Removing the ; didn't work also.